# D3 Graph Won't Show dynamically created JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, d3.js, ejs

I have a function that on page load, getVisualizer() which creates a JSON file of the current user and their friends. The goal here is to visualize the users network. So the end result should be the current users node, attached to nodes labeled with their friend's names.

D3 here is set up to render the graph called "links". I have a sample graph (titled previous_links) I was able to render, but the moment I try to create my own JSON file called "links" it no longer draws. I'm at a loss here, as I've checked that the correct data is being added to the JSON file object- so I believe it may be a formatting issue.

Relevant code is as follows.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <style>....

        </style>
      </head>

    <body>     
      <div id = "trythis" class="container main-section">
      //...basic layout items here...//


    <script>

    var numRequests = 0;

    var links = [];

    //PROBLEM SOMEWHERE IN HERE.--------

    function getVisualizer() {
        $.getJSON('/visualizer', function(data) {
          var n = Object.keys(data).length;
          if (n !== numRequests) {
            for (var key in data) {
              var value = data[key];
              var myObj = {
             "source" : "MyName",    //Test Username variable
             "target" : value       //friends name variable
            };
            //push the object to JSON array
            console.log("The object added is" + JSON.stringify(myObj));
            links.push( myObj );
            }
            numRequests = n;
          }
          console.log("Reached end of function");
        });
      };

      function refresh() {
        getVisualizer();

        //test that item 1 is correct
        console.log(JSON.stringify(links[0]) + "is links 0");
      };


        refresh();


    //PARTIAL ISSUE HERE. THIS GRAPH DRAWS SUCCESSFULLY WHEN RENAMED "links"
    //As you can see, I tried to create the same data structure 
    //above when loading friends and calling "push" for each object.

    //---------SAMPLE GRAPH THAT DRAWS--------------------

    var previous_links = [{
        "source": "Analytics",
        "target": "Science"
    }, {
        "source": "Analytics",
        "target": "Software"
    }, {
        "source": "Analytics",
        "target": "Story"
    }, {
        "source": "Science",
        "target": "Math"
    }, {
        "source": "Science",
        "target": "Statistics"
    }, {
        "source": "Software",
        "target": "R"
    }, {
        "source": "Software",
        "target": "SAS"
    }, {
        "source": "Software",
        "target": "Other"
    }, {
        "source": "Story",
        "target": "Business Communication"
    }, {
        "source": "Story",
        "target": "Visualization"
    }];

    //----------------------------------  

    //Here, I set up the graph for JSON named "links". Question is, how come
    //my newly created version will not draw?

    var nodes = {}

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function (link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
            name: link.source
        });
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
            name: link.target
        });
        link.value = +link.value;
    });

    var width = 900
    height = 300;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(50)
        .charge(-200)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("#trythis").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", click)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 12)
        .style("fill", "#C71585");

    node.append("text")
        .attr("x", 14)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("fill", "#333")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

        node.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }

    function mouseover() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("r", 16);
    }

    function mouseout() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("r", 12);
    }
    // action to take on mouse click
    function click() {
        d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", 22)
            .style("stroke-width", ".5px")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style("fill", "#E34A33")
            .style("font", "17.5px serif");
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .style("fill", "#E34A33")
            .attr("r", 16)
    }

    // action to take on mouse double click
    function dblclick() {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("r", 12)
            .style("fill", "#E34A33");
        d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", 14)
            .style("stroke", "none")
            .style("fill", "#E34A33")
            .style("stroke", "none")
            .style("opacity", 0.6)
            .style("font", "14px serif");
    }





    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time verifying this without an example project to run, but here's what I think has happened:

By the time `links.forEach(function (link) {` runs, `links` still has the value `[]`, because the `function` in `$.getJSON('/visualizer', function(data) {` runs asynchronously, and will likely happen after running the rest of your code.

Try modularising your initialisation code and calling it after your asynchronous code.  Something like this:

```
<script>
  let numRequests = 0
  let links = []
  let nodes = {}
  let link
  let node

  let testData = [{
    "source": "Analytics",
    "target": "Science"
  }, {
    "source": "Analytics",
    "target": "Software"
  }, {
    "source": "Analytics",
    "target": "Story"
  }, {
    "source": "Science",
    "target": "Math"
  }, {
    "source": "Science",
    "target": "Statistics"
  }, {
    "source": "Software",
    "target": "R"
  }, {
    "source": "Software",
    "target": "SAS"
  }, {
    "source": "Software",
    "target": "Other"
  }, {
    "source": "Story",
    "target": "Business Communication"
  }, {
    "source": "Story",
    "target": "Visualization"
  }]


  const addIfUnique = (list, item) => list.indexOf(item) === -1 ? list.concat(item) : list
  const byName = (links, {source, target}) => addIfUnique(addIfUnique(links, source), target)
  const toNode = (name, i) => ({name, index: i})

  function addLinks(data) {
    let names = data.reduce(byName, [])
    const toLink = ({source, target}) => ({
      source: names.indexOf(source),
      target: names.indexOf(target)
    })
    nodes = names.map(toNode)
    links = data.map(toLink)
  }

  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y)

    node.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
  }

  function mouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16)
  }

  function mouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 12)
  }

  function click() {
    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("x", 22)
      .style("stroke-width", ".5px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("fill", "#E34A33")
      .style("font", "17.5px serif")

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style("fill", "#E34A33")
      .attr("r", 16)
  }

  function dblclick() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 12)
      .style("fill", "#E34A33")

    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("x", 14)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("fill", "#E34A33")
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.6)
      .style("font", "14px serif")
  }

  function drawGraph() {
    const width = 900
    const height = 300

    const force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .size([width, height])
      .linkDistance(50)
      .charge(-200)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start()

    const svg = d3.select("#trythis").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")

    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("click", click)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(force.drag)

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .style("fill", "#C71585")

    node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 14)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("fill", "#333")
      .text(d => d.name)
  }

  function verifyItem1IsCorrect() {
    const item1 = JSON.stringify(links[0])
    console.log(`${item1} is links 0`)
  }

  function setUpGraph(data) {
    addLinks(data)
    drawGraph()
    verifyItem1IsCorrect()
  }

  // $.getJSON('/visualizer', setUpGraph)
  setUpGraph(testData)
</script>
```

**EDIT**: The D3.js v3 API has a very specific layout required for the [links](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#links) and [nodes](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#nodes).

The nodes array has objects with a simple integer index in them and a string name, and the links array has objects with source and target attributes, but the source and targets have to be either:

- integers referring to the indices of the nodes; or
- object references to the actual nodes in the nodes array.

Comment: Yes I definitely see what you're saying here- I was getting that links[] was empty. Trying right now and will let you know!

Comment: So, it seems like the correct data is there- it's just stuck in the corner of the screen. I am getting network:266 Uncaught ReferenceError: link is not defined. (occurring in the tick() function) Could this be because "link" is not defined before it is called?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  I saw that after the fact. I'll update this answer with new code (ES6 stuff).

Comment: It's a combination of asynchronous code and scoping: `link` needs to exist in a scope where `tick()` can access it, and it also needs to have a value it can reference.  If the initialisation code runs before the data exists, then it will create a link variable with no data.

Comment: d3.v3.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at n (d3.v3.min.js:4)
    at Object.l.start (d3.v3.min.js:4)
    at drawGraph (network:372)
    at Object.setUpGraph [as success] (network:412)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4) ----it appears the error is something to do with push not being defined- doesn't make sense to me though... especially since we now have links[] initialized at the start

Comment: That's something with D3.js.  Try switching from `d3.v3.min.js` to `d3.v3.js` to see which line comes up in the error.

Comment: appears to be an issue with the source, target, and value- apparently value needs to be defined as a number? I see you've added value into the definition of an object to be inserted into the map , though

Comment: Interesting! I added that because I thought you needed it with this line `link.value = +link.value;`.  You can either remove it or replace it with `value: value || 0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159469/javascript-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-push-of-undefined-d3 looked at this as well. I replaced the line with  value: value || 0 and still get the same error. sorry this is taking a while, just feel like it's very close to working-- I've included it in a fiddle - tried setting "links" to some arbirtrary data http://jsfiddle.net/morganherr98/schuLzo9/

Comment: Just updated the code.  I got it to render in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @rubyquartz Did this update work out for you? Have you ran into any other issues?